# Determining the class of a new sequence using Markov chains

Tags: classification, markov-chain, sequence-analysis

I want to use a Markov chain to classify a new given sequence as from `model+` or `model-`. For that purpose first I trained two sequences from `model+` and `model-`. When the new sequence is given how to say that belongs to which class? Please note the sequences are based on web browsing not biological sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Which algorithm did you use for training with the two sequences?

You can separately train a [Hidden Markov Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) for each sequence. At each given `t`, you find the hidden states, and based on the transition probabilities of these states, you can appoint a real-time probability (practically log probability due to [underflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow)) of belonging to `model+` or `model-`.

Please have a look at [Rabiner's paper on HMM](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf)'s, especially the last two paragraphs on Pg. 261 that talk about training different HMM's for recognizing different words.

Comment: Thanks Zhubarb. I used a First order markov chain model. For this context I just need a first order markov chain not a HMM.

Comment: @Nilani Algiriyage, I am interested. Can you explain how you inmplemented it? Are there any online sources? Also, can you do real-time predictions, like: at `t=21`, `P(model+)= 0.43`, while `P(model-)=0.57` but at `t=22` this changes?